# Declaring algebraic data type to instance of Eq

Tags: haskell

```
data Weekday = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun
```

How do I declare this to an instance of Eq without using `deriving Eq`

Do I have to declare it for every single possibility like:

```
instance Eq Weekday where
                   Mon == Mon = True
                   Mon == _ = False
                   _ == Mon = False
                   Tue == Tue = True
                   ... == ... = ..
```

or is there a smarter solution?

Comment: `deriving Eq` is the "smarter solution". Otherwise, yes, you'll need to define all cases.

Comment: Thank you this was my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's essentially gonna be this unless you want to mess with Template Haskell or GHC's deriving mechanisms.

```
instance Eq Weekday where
  Mon == Mon = True
  Tue == Tue = True
  Wed == Wed = True
  Thu == Thu = True
  Fri == Fri = True
  Sat == Sat = True
  Sun == Sun = True
  _ == _ = False
```

Comment: It might be enough in this case because it's quite unlikely that we'll add a new day of the week in the future but it's a rather dangerous pattern to use: the catch-all case prevents the typechecker from warning you that the definition needs to be modified if you extend the enumeration. It'll just silently return `False` for this extra case.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want, but in this case you can define Eq in terms of Enum.  For example:

```
data Weekday = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun

instance Eq Weekday where
     a == b = fromEnum a == fromEnum b
```

The Enum instance can either be derived, `deriving (Enum)`, or you once again must make a rather verbose instance declaration much like what Fraser has shown.